# Angular: have side effects and return Observable from a method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have this function:

```
  /**
   * Attempt login with provided credentials
   * @returns {Observable<number>} the status code of HTTP response
   */
  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<number> {
    let body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.append('grant_type', 'password');
    body.append('username', username);
    body.append('password', password);

    return this.http.post(Constants.LOGIN_URL, body, null)
      .do(res => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
          this.authTokenService.setAuthToken(res.json().auth_token);
        }
      })
      .map(res => res.status)
      .catch(err => { return Observable.throw(err.status) });
  }
```

This function attempts to perform login and returns `Observable<number>` that the caller can use in order to be notified of the HTTP code of the response.

This seems to work, but I have one problem: if the caller just calls the function without subscribing to the returned `Observable`, `do` function is not called and the received auth token is not being saved.

Documentation of `do` states:

> Note: this is different to a subscribe on the Observable. If the
>   Observable returned by do is not subscribed, the side effects
>   specified by the Observer will never happen. do therefore simply spies
>   on existing execution, it does not trigger an execution to happen like
>   subscribe does.

What I'd like to achieve, is to have this side effect regardless of whether the caller of `login()` subscribed or not. What should I do?

Comment: This method returns an observable. What's the point of calling it if you are not going to subscribe to it's response? (you won't be making this request if you don't subscribe)

Comment: @echonax, this method is in service. There might be multiple clients - some of them will subscribe, others won't. I don't want the functionality of the service to depend on the semantics of external usage.

Comment: you can call `subscribe()` inside the `login()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by @Maximus, by design, cold Observable (like http call) will not emit any data before you subscribe to them. So your `.do()` callback will never get called.

Hot Observables on the other hand will emit data without caring if there is a subscriber or not.

You can convert your cold `Observable` to a `ConnectableObservable` using the `publish()` operator. That Observable will start emitting when its `connect()` method get called.

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable < number > {
  let body = new URLSearchParams();
  body.append('grant_type', 'password');
  body.append('username', username);
  body.append('password', password);
  let request = this.http.post(Constants.LOGIN_URL, body, null)
    .do(res => {
      if (res.status == 200) {
        this.authTokenService.setAuthToken(res.json().auth_token);
      }
    })
    .map(res => res.status)
    .catch(err => {
      return Observable.throw(err.status)
    }).publish();
  request.connect();
  // type assertion because nobody needs to know it is a ConnectableObservable
  return request as Observable < number > ; 
}
```

As @Maximus stated. If the subscription happen after the ajax call as completed, you won't get notified of the result. To handle this case you can use `publishReplay(1)` instead of simple `publish()`. `PublishReplay(n)` will repeat the last n-th elements emitted by the source `Observable` to new subscribers.

Comment: you will have a new request for each call to login

Comment: That's not OP's question. (BTW: so does your solution.)

Comment: no, my solution doesn't send the request each time. that is why I use the variable `sent`.

Comment: also bear in mind that with `publish().connect()` all subscriptions to `login()` will not be notified once the `http.get()` completes

Comment: @n00dl3, this seems to work, but I have one issue. `authTokenService.setAuthToken()` is always called with `undefined` argument. Looks like `res.json().auth_token` doesn't resolve to the actual data I'm receiving. Do you happen to know what the problem is?

Comment: @Vasiliy no idea. Are you sure your response has that `auth_token` property ?

Comment: @n00dl3, nop :( Probably some issue with the test driver. Accepting your answer as it seems to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my answer below I assume that you got used to behavior provided by `Promises` in previous versions of `HTTP` in AngularJS:

```
 login(username: string, password: string): Observable<number> {
    return this.http.post(Constants.LOGIN_URL, body, null)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
          this.authTokenService.setAuthToken(res.json().auth_token);
        }
      })
      .then(res => res.status)
      .catch(err => { return Observable.throw(err.status) });
```

The observable returned from `this.http.get()` call is `cold` observable. It means that it will not start doing anything unless someone subscribes to it. That is by design. All operators that you chain to the returned observables don't do anything as well since there's no subscription.

You need to subscribe to make a request and then share the result with future subscribers. And I think `AsyncSubject` is a good candidate here:

```
  sent = false;
  s = new AsyncSubject();

  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<number> {   
    if (!this.sent) {
      this.http.post(Constants.LOGIN_URL, body, null)
        .do(res => {
          if (res.status == 200) {
            this.authTokenService.setAuthToken(res.json().auth_token);
          }
        })
        .map(res => res.status)
        .catch(err => { return Observable.throw(err.status) })
        .subscribe(s);

      this.sent = true;
    }

    return s;
  }
```

In this way only one http call will be made and all operators include `do` will run only once. After that, the returned result will be cached in [AsyncSubject](https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs/subjects/async-subject) and it will pass it along to all future subscribers.

Comment: You don't need a subject. Plus your code is wrong. How a constant set to `false` can become `true` ?

Comment: no idea why the downvote, this really solves his problem. Even though I still have difficulties understanding what the issue is.

Comment: @n00dl3, how come I don't need a subject? Why make multiple calls for authentication if one would do? Also you probably realize that I don't put the code exactly as it should be. **I write pseudocode** where typos are expected things

Comment: @PierreDuc, I believe that the OP worked with promises before where if you wrote `this.http.get().then(do)...` would make request instantly without requiring any subscription to `then`. This is `hot` behavior and that is what I think OP expects from the existing `http.get()`

Comment: You still don't need a subject, you can convert to hot observable. Your `sent` variable will always be false when the method is called so it is useless.

Comment: @n00dl3, how can I convert to hot observable? I don't understand why sent will always be false, I change it to `true` when the call is made. Why don't you provide your solution?

Comment: You can convert using `publish()` and `connect()`. it will always be `false` when the method is called as it is not a class property, but a simple variable. Whenever you call that method, `sent` is `false`, so what is the point in keeping it ?

Comment: so make it a class property, what's the problem? again, I dont post tested solutions, I expect OP to do that

Comment: I'm sorry if I offended you, that wasn't my intention. But the problem is your solution is wrong. That little difference makes your solution pointless. You don't know OP's code, you imagine that you can handle the whole session state with a single boolean ? You don't even reset it to `false` when the request has completed. What if there is another call to login with different parameters ? you will send back the same `Observable` with old login and password ? If you only talked about AsyncSubject I wouldn't have downvoted.

Comment: I was answering having in mind a certain pattern from previous HTTP clients. I added this information to the answer.